# How do I show what type of object is getting returned from an array or method?

Tags: objective-c

I have an array that can store different types of objects.  When I retrieve that object I'd like to print that object type to the log.  I can't seem to find a method that does this. I don't want to print the contents of the object.

I'd like the log to say something like "NSString" or "NSDictionary".

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
id anObject = [myArray objectAtIndex:42];
NSLog(@"%@", [anObject class]);
```

(To be totally correct, it should be:)

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([anObject class]));
```

Comment: What is the difference between Class that's returned by class method and NSString? For example, NSPasteBoard canRead method can only receive NSString, but I could pass canRead:[NSImage class]. Does it mean Class here is the same as NSString?